# trying sample app in AFNetworking2 for iOS but getting cancelled error

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm not an iOS dev but am trying to get up to speed with an AFNetworking1 app that our company has. I am looking at AFNetworking2 and wanted to test it out. I downladed the master and tried to run the sample app which makes a call to https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global. However, when I open the .xcodeproj file and run in the simulator, I get a cancelled error and when I NSLog the error from the failure block:

```
2013-12-06 10:47:28.239 AFNetworking iOS Example[14566:70b] this was a failure Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo=0x907ba60 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

A screen shot is here and is called from the bottom of this snipped in the main UITableViewController

```
- (void)reload:(__unused id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [Post globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"within here");
        if (!error) {
            self.posts = posts;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"there was an error");
        }

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    }];

    [UIAlertView showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:task delegate:nil];
```

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Error -999 appears when an asynchronous networking request is cancelled.  This doesn't happen in the code you posted, but it might be in `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:`.  Can you post that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue.  Tried 2.0.3 and the issue was resolved.

Here's a link to a ZIP archive: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/archive/2.0.3.zip